# How to assign value to a parameter of class method from an outside function?

Tags: python, class

https://pastebin.com/AELyLF5z

```
class Bar(object):
    def__init__(self, **kwargs):
       self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
       
    def draw(numballs):
       print(numballs)


def experiment(bar, numballs):
    //i need to use bar object to call on the draw method but draw method requires numballs 


bar1 = Bar(a=4, b=5, c=3, d=2)
numballs = 5
experiment(bar1, numballs)
```

So the project I am working on to learn python is one of the projects listed in FreeCodeCamp. The assignment wants a function outside of a class that will call on a method that is inside of it. In the pseudo-code I wrote, the experiment function needs to call on the draw method but the draw method requires a parameter that is given in the experiment function. How can I assign the value for the method from my experiment function?

Comment: You didn't write pseudo-code, it's real Python code.

Comment: learning a programming language also means making mistakes and finding patterns that led you to making them and prevent YOU from finding them. don't miss on that opportunity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the call the method on the instance like this : `my_instance.method_name()`

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    def draw(self, numballs):         
        print(numballs)
        print(self.a, self.b) # to print instance attribut

def experiment(bar: Bar, numballs: int):
    bar.draw(numballs)
```

Also you were missing `self` argument in `draw` method, that represents the instance that you called the method on

Comment: it says 'Bar' object has no attribute 'draw'

Comment: @GirthyLampost Your indentation is wrong. `def draw` should not be inside `def __init__`

Comment: @GirthyLampost your `draw` method if over-indented, it is INSIDE your `__init__` method. And also miss all `self.` before instance attributs https://pastebin.com/rJCR7JYw

Comment: it says, numballs is not defined

Comment: yes i noticed. i fixed the indentation but now its saying numballs is not defined

Comment: i edited my pastebin to updated code it says numballs is not defined but its a function parameter... why would i need to define it in the class?

Comment: yep i fixed it.. my bad

Comment: the only problem i have now is that my contents[] cannot be accessed in the method

Comment: @GirthyLampost Read my pastebin. you may use `self.contents` in the init and the draw method, if not it is local to the method, it should be related to the instance

Comment: thank u so much. im gona study this syntax now so i memorie it

Comment: @GirthyLampost You may understand the concept, of objects, instances, attributs of instances, local variables ;) Google that words and learn that ;) You can think about accepting my answer so now ;) (green tick on left)